# Most efficient efficient way to deal with index/match returning 0 instead of blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel sheet:

[image]

In the yellow cells I want to get values from the green cells through index/match. I need to avoid blank cells being shown as zeroes.

I can use =if(index(...) = "", "", index(...)) but this means excel runs index/match twice for each cell so it's not ideal for large spreadsheets.

I could use =index(...)&"" which is neat and simple but the resulting values would be actually text so I would not be able to perform calculations on them:

[image]

The other alternative would be =LET(value,INDEX(...),IF(value="","",value))
which is not as neat but I assume has the advantage of executing index/match only once for each cell. Is that correct and are there better alternatives?

Comment: You LET approach seems efficiënt.

Comment: Either `=IFNA(INDEX(B$2:B$4,MATCH(E2,A$2:A%4,0)),"")`, or if you have MS365, `=XLOOKUP(E2,A$2:A$4,B$2:B$4,"")` and copy down. Or to spill, simply `=XLOOKUP(E2:E4,A2:A4,B2:B4,"")`. If necessary, you can always replace `B$2:B$4` with `IF(B$2:B$4="","",B$2:B$4)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 since the lookup value is no issue, but it's the return value being empty to be returned as empty, your IF-approach is necessary. Something like: `=XLOOKUP(D2:D4,A2:A4,IF(B2:B4="","",B2:B4),"")` but his LET approach is fine as well. IFNA doesn't deal with emptyness of return value, since it returns 0, not an N/A-error

Comment: @younggotti since your example returns the exact same as the original, would you even need a lookup or index match, or could you deal with the original range directly maybe?

Comment: @P.b. You are right: the example is oversimplified. In the actual spreadsheet the two "a" columns are not aligned so an index match is needed. I also can't use lookup, as I need to get data from several columns, using a dynamic col reference (columns are not aligned as well)

Comment: If there will never be a `0` in the actual data, you could use a custom number format to hide the zero's:  `0;-0;;`

Comment: @younggotti If your data could be in different columns, it would be a different question. Also, could a value of `a` have multiple values to be used in your calculation? Is the question also the end goal, or is the end goal to calculate the average (mean) as in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

My formula is the same and it returns zero because I've activated that option. Easy to handle and easy to custom each worksheet based on your needs.

> [Hide or display all zero values on a
> worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20File%20%3E%20Options%20%3E%20Advanced,have%20zero%20value%20check%20box.)

To be honest, activating/deactivating this option probably will be the most efficient one. It's just a few clicks and you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `VLookup()` for this?

Hereby an easy example:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(E3;B$3:C$5;2;FALSE)=0;"";VLOOKUP(E3;B$3:C$5;2;FALSE))
```

It looks as follows on screen:

[image]